# Как настроить кодировку UTF-8 на сайте и сервере?

Tags: cp1251, кодировка, utf-8, php

Ситуация такая: Начал создавать страницы для сайта. По умолчанию стояла кодировка `Windows-1251`, а базу данных в `utf-8`. Затем страницы перекодировал в `UTF-8` без `BOM`. На данный момент настройки базы такие:

```
MySQL connection collation:  utf8_general_ci

MySQL    
 - Server: localhost via TCP/IP
 - Server version: 5.1.40-community
 - Protocol version: 10
 - User: root@localhost
 - MySQL charset:  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server  
 - Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.3.3
 - MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 300533 $
 - PHP extension: mysql
```

А в итоге: информация из базы выводиться корректно, а вот то, что было написано на самих страницах видно только тогда, когда кодировку в обозревателе выставишь `UTF-8`, 
соответственно то, что выводилось из базы будет на кракозябрах. Подскажите, как решить?

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста ссылку, вы или так перекодировали или я что-то не так понял...<br>
Если html страница будет в `utf-8` и вы поставите в meta `charset cp1251` то нормально страница не будет отображаться никак, вы уверены в том что ваши страницы в UTF-8?

Comment: Суть в том, что все страницы (.php) пересохранены в UTF-8 по средствам Akel Pad, и charset в них я тоже поменял везде c Windows-1251 на UTF-8 вручную! Всё, что приходит с сервера отлично отображается а вот сами страницы хоть и все перекодированы в UTF-8, показывают кракозябры!
Ссылку дать не могу пока тестирую на Денвере!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вначале файла

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

сразу после соединения с БД

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

чтобы наверняка )

Comment: может вопрос перечитете?.. Причем тут mysql?

Comment: недосмотрел :) исправил, спс.

Comment: mysql выдаёт данные в кодировке windows-1251 а страницы у меня в utf-8? вот и получается. То, что браузер автоматом ставит кодировку windows-1251, а то что прописано на страницах в utf-8 выводит на кракозябрах.

Comment: как он может выдавать в win если у вас
>MySQL connection collation:  utf8_general_ci

исправил ответ, и то и то попробуйте вставить..

Comment: Ваще загадка!

Comment: ТС отдохни немного, подумай хорошо и потом решай проблему, чтото мне подсказывает что там все очень просто(иначе и не может быть собственно), кстати - браузеру по барабану в какой кодировке страница, какую вы ему скажете такую он и поставит....

Answer (score 1):

В итоге помогло только 
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне кажется, что html-файлы, которые выводят инфу и базы, имеют кодировку `Windows-1251`. В мета может стоять

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

, но сами символы на кодировке `Windows-1251`. Для проверки, попробуйте открыть, например, в `AkelPad` проблемную страницу в кодировке `UTF-8`. Если русский текст будет не нормальным, тогда пересохраните в кодировке `UTF-8`.

Comment: Вполне возможно, суть в том что проблема явно не на сервере а на клиенте, в данном случае тем или иным образом связана именно с кодировкой html'я, но никак не с Mysql'ем...

Comment: Открыл один из файлов в Akel Pad? кодировку пишет 65001 (UTF-8) *BOM, оно и понятно я лично перекодировал страницы! Проблема та же!

Answer (score 0):

Кодировку файлов со статическим сервером не забыли поменять на UTF-8? Только не путайте с параметром `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`! Это маленько другое!

Comment: Немного не понял, где именно нужно поменять кодировку, ... на сервере? Всё, что приходит с сервера отлично отображается а вот сами страницы хоть и все перекодированы в UTF-8, показывают кракозябры!

Comment: Еще раз. 
1. Из MySQL_ тяните в UTF-8, в браузере стоит кодировка UTF-8,
2. Заголовок посылает браузеру  charset=UTF-8.
3.ТО что написано статестически в любом файле (html, tpl, php и тд) - отображается криво.
Тогда остается только одно. В редакторе нужно сохранить файлы (html, tpl, php и тд) которые обрабатываются сервером в кодировку UTF-8.
Пример в Total Commander . Кодировки-> Сохранить в Unicode-> UTF-8

Comment: Не нашёл в в Total Commander  Кодировки!

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте эти строки в .htaccess

```
AddCharset utf-8 .php .html .js
AddDefaultCharset off
```

Вы в рутовую папку кинули и не пашет? Это на локале или на глобале?

В общем, если это на денвере, то, что я написал изначально, обычно решает все проблемы... Так что х3... валите в пхп.ини и там кодировку дефолтную меняйте...

"Когда кодировку в обозревателе выставишь Windows-1251" чел, если в вин1251 норм читает, значит, инфа реально записана в вин1251... скорей всего проблема с тем, что инфа у вас в базе в вин1251, хоть вы и чарсет там проставили утфный... вы как инфу в базу вносили?

Сделайте дамп базы без сжатия и поменяйте кодировку блокнотом. Мне вроде когда-то такое прокатило. ) Ну попробуйте по крайней мере...

Откройте в блокноте, гляньте какая кодировка у дампа. Поменяйте на утф, если там вин1251.

Comment: Да друг, так и получается! Инфа из базы читаема когда в настройках браузера выбираешь кодировку Windows-1251. Как исправить кодировку на UTF-8 в базе?

Дамп сделал там Windows-1251 нет ни единой записи!