# не выводит результат json

Tags: php, json

Есть метод класса:

```
public function execute() {
  $this->response["response"] = [];
  array_push($this->response["response"], $this->result);
  print json_encode($this->response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

На локальном сервере данный метод выводит результат в `JSON`, а на хостинге - пустая страница. В логах никаких ошибок нет, поддержка его включена. В чем может быть проблема?

Upd. Не выводит результат, который содержит русские символы.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Попробуйте вот так.

```
public function execute() {
    $this->response["response"] = [];
    array_push($this->response["response"], $this->result);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($this->response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает.

Comment: Тогда скорее всего проблема с кодировкой на сервере.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/42729/179650

Comment: У меня кодировка настроена и на хостинге и на локалке одинаково.